# How to populate Beans property in SpringContext once it is loaded

Tags: spring

I would like to update the property of a bean in spring application context based on the objects I receive as Input.Below is my Piece of code.

```
There are many other beans here only required beans.
<bean id="getReportParameterWithDetailsBean" class="com.oracle.xmlns.oxp.service.publicreportservice.GetReportParameters">
   <property name="reportRequest" >
        <ref bean="reportRequestWithDetails"/>
    </property>
    <property name="userID"  value = "#{userDetails.userId}" />
    <property name="password"  value = "#{userDetails.password}" />
</bean>

 <bean id ="userDetails" class="com.oracle.xmlns.oxp.service.DataObjects.UserDetails">
    <property name="userId"  value = <Get the values from Reciever BEan> />
    <property name="password"  value = <Get the values from Reciever BEan> />
```

User details is the bean I receive as Input in a receiver class and I would like the values to be available in the bean "getReportParameterWithDetailsBean" .

getReportParameterWithDetailsBean has respective setters and getters,it's a generated Stub , hence too big.

Below is the code for Reciever class which has "UserDetails" as on of it's property.
    public class PublicReportServiceClientReciever {
    public PublicReportServiceClientReciever(){

```
}

public PublicReportServiceClientReciever(UserDetails userDetails){
    this.user=userDetails;
}
private UserDetails user;

public UserDetails getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(UserDetails user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public void runARG(UserDetails userDetails){
    ConfigurableApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

    this.user = userDetails;
    //GetReportParameters will intuen be used in this bean  PublicServiceReportReadWithDetails  
    PublicServiceReportReadWithDetails reader = new PublicServiceReportReadWithDetails();
    reader.readreports();
    ((ClassPathXmlApplicationContext) context).close();
}
```

Reciever class' runARG is called from external component which provides me UserDetails object and I need to set it in  the xml piece of code shown above.
Please help me in achieving this.Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have setters for the code you wish to update? The bean is regular Java class that is wired with the Spring.

Comment: You can user `setter` methods to set the value of `getReportParameterWithDetailsBean` bean.As it is singleton bean values will get reflected when you request it again.

Comment: Please provide the source code for `GetReportParameters` class and example of loading the application context and data input. Problem is clear but not what you have done so far.